# Como percorrer uma árvore binária?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tendo dificuldade para adicionar um elemento em uma árvore binária pois não sei como percorrer...

Nó da árvore

```
public class NodeBinaryTree extends BinaryTree{
    NodeBinaryTree left;
    NodeBinaryTree right;
    int elemento;

    public NodeBinaryTree(int elemento){
        this.elemento = elemento;
        left = right = null;
    }

}
```

Estrutura da árvore

```
public class BinaryTree {
    NodeBinaryTree root;


    public BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return root == null;
    }

    public void add(int elemento, NodeBinaryTree arvore){
        NodeBinaryTree aux = new NodeBinaryTree(elemento);
        if(isEmpty()){
            root = aux;
        }else{
            aux = aux.left;
            //quero percorrer a arvore em pré ordem
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: "percorrer a árvore" (seja em pré ordem, pós ordem ou in ordem) é uma coisa, "adicionar elementos" é outra coisa. No primeiro caso você não modifica a árvore, apenas lista seus elementos numa ordem definida. No segundo, é simplesmente uma questão de se determinar **onde** você quer inserir. Você *poderia* escolher arbitrariamente, mas na prática, não faz muito sentido se falar em árvore se não há uma ordem total entre os elementos, como apontado na [resposta do user1620696](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18838/215).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando se utiliza uma árvore binária supõe-se que você pode comparar os elementos. Se isso não é possível você precisa de outra estrutura de dados. O algorítimo é bem simples:

```
Se a árvore A está vazia
    Construir nova árvore A com o item I como nó e subárvores vazias
Caso contrário
    Se o valor do item I for menor ao do nó
        Se a subárvore a esquerda estiver vazia
            Construir nova subárvore E a esquerda com I como nó e subárvores vazias
        Caso contrário 
            Inserir I na subárvore à esquerda
    Caso contrário
        Se a subárvore a direita estiver vazia
            Construir nova subárvore D a direita com I como nó e subárvores vazias
        Caso contrário
            Inserir I na subárvore à direita
```

Perceba o seguinte: esse algorítmo é recursivo sendo que o caso base é quando a árvore está vazia. Nesse caso, inserir significa construir a árvore e colocar o item como valor do nó. O resto se baseia na comparação. Quando você vai inserir numa árvore não vazia você se pergunta: o valor do nó é maior que do item dado? Se sim, você quer colocar isso na esquerda.

Colocar na esquerda então tem dois casos: a árvore a esquerda esta vazia, então você usa o caso base, ou então a arvore a esquerda não está vazia e você usa recursão e manda inserir na árvore a esquerda.

Daí pensamento análogo pro outro caso: se o nó é menor ou igual ao valor do item então você faz isso pra direita.

Agora que você já sabe o algorítmo, vamos ver como isso pode ser feito orientado a objetos em Java com uma árvore de inteiros (em C# você poderia fazer uma árvore de coisas genéricas desde que sejam comparáveis, não sei se Java permite isso). Basicamente a árvore deve ter o nó e subárvores à direita e esquerda. Esses são os atributos do seu tipo.

Com relação à metodos só precisamos pra isso o método de inserir items e um construtor. O construtor vai tomar conta de não precisarmos fazer a primeira verificação do algorítmo: a única forma de construir uma árvore binária vai ser dando um elemento pra ser colocado no nó. Dessa forma ela nunca vai estar vazia. O construtor já vai setar as referências pras subarvores como null indicando que elas estão vazias pra poder fazer a verificação do algorítmo.

No fim vai ficar assim:

```
class ArvoreBinariaInteiros
{
    private int valorNo;
    private ArvoreBinariaInteiros subarvoreEsquerda;
    private ArvoreBinariaInteiros subarvoreDireita;

    public ArvoreBinariaInteiros(int valorNo)
    {
        this.valorNo = valorNo;
        this.subarvoreEsquerda = null;
        this.subarvoreDireita = null;
    }

    public void InserirItem(int item)
    {
         int valorNoAtual = valorNo;
         if ( item < valorNoAtual )
         {
             if (subarvoreEsquerda == null) 
             {
                 subarvoreEsquerda = new ArvoreBinariaInteiros(item);
             }
             else
             {
                 subarvoreEsquerda.InserirItem(item);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if (subarvoreDireita == null)
             {
                 subarvoreDireita = new ArvoreBinariaInteiros(item);
             }
             else
             {
                 subarvoreDireita.InserirItem(item);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Os atributos subarvoredaesquerda e direita devem fazer parte da ArvoreBinariaInteiros? Ou posso criar uma classe para estes atributos? e toda vez que passo pelo metodo InserirItem é criado um novo objeto ou os atributos da classe permanecem estaticos? (não sei se voce compreendeu o que eu quis dizer aqui)

Comment: E caso eu queira fazer com que o usuario escolha onde este estará adicionando o item (direita ou esquerda) eu poderia fazer assim:
Exemplo adicionando à esquerda (0 = esquerda)

    public void add(int elemento, int pos){

        NodeBinaryTree aux = new NodeBinaryTree(elemento);

        if(isEmpty()){

            root = aux;

        }else if (pos == 0 && aux.left == null){

            aux.left = new NodeBinaryTree(elemento);

        }else if(pos == 0){

            aux = aux.left;

            add(elemento, pos);

        }

    }

Não sei como separar as linhas

Comment: Primeiro, as subarvores são referências a outras arvores. Nesse caso a intenção é que eles sejam atributos da árvore mesmo. Você até poderia envelopar em outro tipo, mas isso só complicaria o design e não ajudaria. Com relação à sua pergunta, não entendi. Não tem nenhum atributo estático aí. Com relação à escolher onde adicionar, isso já seria outra estrutura de dados. A árvore binária é desse jeito aí, porque a intenção é justamente organizar dados comparáveis. De uma olhada aqui http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria.

Comment: Se quiser generalizar sua solução, há em Java a interface `Comparable<T>` com o método `compareTo(T arg)`: que retorna "um valor negativo" se o `this` for menor que o argumento, "um valor positivo" se o `this` for maior, e `0` se ambos forem iguais. Pode-se também usar um objeto auxiliar para isso - `Comparator<T>` - mas já é uma outra história... (P.S. tipos primitivos não poderiam ser usados nesse caso, mas o autoboxing de `int` para `Integer` por exemplo resolveria - já que `Integer` implementa `Comparable<Integer>`)

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @mgibsonbr, então é bem parecido com o C#. Não sabia que o Java também tem genéricos como C#.

Comment: entendi obrigado pela ajuda!